# Top of list item is being cut off

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't seem to figure out what is making my list items look this way. It looks like the list item doesn't take up the entire height of the ul but I can't figure out what to do to make it work correctly. I have tried tinkering with just about every css combination I can think of (margin, padding, negative margin, defining height, floating elements). Any suggestions?

http://www.connectroot.com/directory/

---

[image]

Comment: Are you on about the black menu or the purple menu? It looks fine on my screen.

Comment: Although you weren't asking, I think it looks better this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use background: not background-image:

This should work:

```
.filter {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)), color-stop(1, rgb(102,51,102)));
}
```

This will make the text look a bit wierd but you can fix that with some padding

```
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you have positioned the background here

```
ul li {
background-image: url('images/cr-bullet.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 5px; //cause of the problem
padding-left: 30px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

remove this `background-position: 0px 5px;` and it should be solved

Or add `background-position: 0;` to your `.filter{ css }`